# Embedding image in email Python

Tags: python, email, sendmail, html-email, spam

Code used for sending an image embedded email using python is given below.

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage

# Define these once; use them twice!
strFrom = 'from@sender.com'
strTo = 'to@example.com'

# Create the root message and fill in the from, to, and subject headers
msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
msgRoot['Subject'] = 'test message'
msgRoot['From'] = strFrom
msgRoot['To'] = strTo
msgRoot.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'

# Encapsulate the plain and HTML versions of the message body in an
# 'alternative' part, so message agents can decide which they want to display.
msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msgRoot.attach(msgAlternative)

msgText = MIMEText('This is the alternative plain text message.')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

# We reference the image in the IMG SRC attribute by the ID we give it below
msgText = MIMEText('<b>Some <i>HTML</i> text</b> and an image.<br><img src="cid:image1"><br>Nifty!', 'html')
msgAlternative.attach(msgText)

# This example assumes the image is in the current directory
fp = open('test.jpg', 'rb')

msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()

# Define the image's ID as referenced above
msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image1>')
msgRoot.attach(msgImage)

# Send the email (this example assumes SMTP authentication is required)
import smtplib
smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
smtp.sendmail(strFrom, strTo, msgRoot.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

My problem is very specific to the **receiver** email server. I used the same code to send an email to a **GMail** id. It worked fine. But here, the receiver email server is considering this email as **spam** whenever I tries to embed an image in the email as shown in the above code. If I am not trying to **embed the image**, then both html and plain text emails are getting received at the destination as expected.
I tried also embedding images with static http urls as the image src. But then also the problem exists. But when i tried using some **https** image urls, the emails where properly received at the receiver side.

The receiver side email filtering is powered by **postini**.

What might be the problem? Is there any way by which I can modify the above code to get rid of this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the receiving server add any spam headers to the email? They can give you a hint what it doesn't like.

Comment: An image accompanying a small amount of text is seen as a sign of an attempt to bypass the spam filter by putting the spam message in the image.

Comment: RossRidge's comment is correct and as close to an answer as you're going to get Nidhin Joseph.  You should try sending the email again except with a much larger amount of text included along with your image and see if it's not flagged then.

Comment: I tried. But the same result.

Comment: Is the receiver email server a corporate one ? If yes, anti-spam filter can be configured to paranoid level. I once saw a mail server that rejected as "dangerous" any mail with an attached zip file. Instead of trying to guess, ask for the actual rules - or rather ask specifically why your email was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this answer:
[Python: Mail sent by script is marked as spam by Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445528/python-mail-sent-by-script-is-marked-as-spam-by-gmail)

Another option - to avoid been marked as SPAM - is to use some service like AWS SES.